# Multiple gwtupload component on same page

Tags: gwt, gwtupload

I'm using `gwtupload` lib for uploading file(s) in my GWT project. https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/wiki/GwtUpload_GettingStarted

**Case**: I've 3 - 4 `MultiUploader` on same page. Its uploading fine. But when I try to upload same file in other component its not allowing. I figured out that if we click on remove button maintained by gwtupload. Its allow to upload same file on other component. So how to fire remove button click. Check image attached below. [image]

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is in this way by design, gwtupload prevents uploading the same file-name if it was successful previously in any instance of uploaders.

You can disable the default feature just calling the `avoidRepeatFiles` method though.

```
    MultiUploader uploader1 = new MultiUploader();
    uploader1.avoidRepeatFiles(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

After digging down source code of `gwtupload`. I found the solution. If you want to have multiple `SingleUploader` or `MultiUploader` on same page. You need to change below lines and need to create `.jar` file of `gwtupload`.

```
private static HashSet<String> fileDone = new HashSet<String>();
private static HashSet<String> fileUploading = new HashSet<String>();
private static List<String> fileQueue = new ArrayList<String>();
```

to (Remove `static`)

```
private HashSet<String> fileDone = new HashSet<String>();
private HashSet<String> fileUploading = new HashSet<String>();
private List<String> fileQueue = new ArrayList<String>();
```

in File `Uploader.java` located in package `gwtupload.client`